# How to move a sprite on a slope in chipmunk Spacemanager

Tags: ios, cocos2d, chipmunk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to move the object(tanker ) on slope image in chipmunk Spacemanager](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/24764/how-to-move-the-objecttanker-on-slope-image-in-chipmunk-spacemanager)

I have used one polygon shape image (terrain) in my game. It's just like a mountain, and now I want to move the tanker on a mountain path from one side to the other and then turn around at the edge of the screen and go back. I don't understand the method to move the tanker on the slope (image) path in chipmunk spacemanager.

When collision detection happens like that, if any bomb falls on the slope (image of mountain) then I want to do a little damage to the slope (image of mountain) like [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vleq3Wa_jZs).